# using PN532 chip on arduino

Tags: nfc

I've recently purchased an NFC-PN532 module online, which I connected to my arduino board and tried to get working. After connecting the pins and using the PN532 adafruit lib I encountered and error where the board was not being picked up. I was using the 'readMifareClassic' example from the lib and uploaded the example to the board and it resulted in the image below where I would receive a '?' or the first print output which is 'hello' in the code. [image: image of the result output in serial monitor]

I'm not that experienced with NFC atm and so im seeking some guidance on what may be the issue. If you need more information please leave a comment.

Thank you

Comment: the example has 115200 baud for Serial. your Serial Monitor is set to 9600 baud

Comment: thanks Juraj, but the chip is not being picked up now and feel as though it might be due to the wiring though i connected the pins according to the code, yet its not picking it up

Comment: but that is a different Question

Answer (score 0):

A very common error when PN532 module is not recognized, is that you are not using the right bus (I2C, SPI, UART).

Make sure:

In Arduino sketch make sure to follow carefully the lines that need to be commented out.

On the PN532 make sure that DIP switches match your bus configuration